# Sum multiple COUNTIF statements in a single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with an attendance sheet, and I am trying to calculate how many people showed up for 4 or more events in a given month.

I am trying to write a formula that needs to count, for each row, whether there are 4 or more “x”s between a given range of columns.

I believe the logic is as follows: If the count of “x” is >= 4, then assign it a value of 1 otherwise assigned it a 0. Loop through each row and then add all those values.

So I can obviously write the first part,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:E, “x”)>=4, 1, 0)
```

**Question 1** How do I sum all those values for, say, rows 1 to 10?

**Solution**: `=SUM(1*(((B1:B10="x") +(C1:C10="x")+(D1:D10="x")+(E1:E10="x"))>=4))` Thank you, CRondao.

**Follow-up:** Similarly, with the same attendance sheet, I need to calculate whether a particular person attended either of the two sessions on Friday (Session 1 is Column J and Sessions 2 is column K) and either of the two sessions on Saturday (Sessions 1 is Column L and Session 2 is Column M). I have a formula written that assigns a value of 1 if the person attends at least 1 session on both Friday and Saturday:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(COUNTIF(B1:C1, "x")>=1, 1, 0)+IF(COUNTIF(D1:E1, "x")>=1, 1, 0))=2, 1, 0)
```

**Question 2:** How do I sum all those values for, say, rows 1 to 10?

Comment: My apologies, yes it needs to be four columns. B:E should have been referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula:

```
=SUM(1*(((J1:J10="x") +(K1:K10="x")+(L1:L10="x")+(M1:M10="x")+(N1:N10="x"))>=4))
```

Here I assume columns J to N, and only rows 1 to 10, but you see the general idea
Dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter in the end

Comment: Or replace SUM by SUMPRODUCT and you dont need Ctrl Shift Enter